# How do I check random numbers in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I have numbers that can be in a certain range in red square and somehow I need to check if the number in the square is in this range using cypress

[image]

```
cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area').contains('0.36')

cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area').contains('0.17')

cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area').contains('0.02')

cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area').contains('0')

cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area').contains('0')
```

now there are specific numbers and I check them using contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chaijs range check `within(low,high)`.

Assume an individual element for each number, for example `<li>`

```js
cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area li')  // select all elements for numbers 
  .each(num => {
    expect(+num).to.be.within(0, 0.4)   // "+num" convert text to number
  })
```

or

```js
cy.get('.details > .justui_scroll-area li')  
  .each(num => {
    cy.wrap(+num).should('be.within', 0, 0.4)
  })
```

Comment: I don't understand a bit how it works, where does this function get the number from? And I didn’t say it’s not li it’s an element with flex inside and therefore doesn’t work like that

Comment: I understand thank you